# Passing value from edit in line to database

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me on how to get the edited value and passing it to the database? I don't really understand how `jquery.inlineedit.js` works that much. What parameter should I use to get the value and pass it to a PHP page?

but here is my partial code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $counter = 0;
        $(".editme2").inlineEdit({control: 'textarea'});
        $("#hide").click(function(){
            if ($counter < 10){ 
                $counter++;
                $('#container').show( );
                $('#container').append( '<div class="inside" style="background: yellow; width: 400px;"><p class="editme2" id="edited'+$counter+'">Click me to add text and drag me to where you want me to be</p></div>');
                $( '.inside' ).draggable({ containment: '#there' });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is my html code:

```
<body>
    <button id="hide">Add Text</button>
    <div id="container" align="center" style="display:none; background: blue; width: 600px;">
        </div>
    <div id="there" style="background: red; width: 600px; height: 500px;">
    <h3>drop here</h3>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @sinetheta https://github.com/caphun/jquery.inlineedit

Answer (score 0):

The author provides a "save" hook in the options. You'll need to define it, and provide a target for your information. There is a [save exmaple](https://github.com/caphun/jquery.inlineedit/blob/master/demos/save.html) with an appropriate [php file](https://github.com/caphun/jquery.inlineedit/blob/master/demos/save.php) to process the form. With your setup it would look something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // setup common ajax setting
        $.ajaxSetup({
            url: 'save.php',
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            timeout: 500
        });
        $(".editme2").inlineEdit({
            control: 'textarea',
            value: $.ajax({ data: { 'action': 'get' } }).responseText,
            save: function(event, data) {
                var html = $.ajax({
                    data: { 'action': 'save', 'value': data.value }
                }).responseText;

                alert("id: " + this.id );

                return html === 'OK' ? true : false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Since his example saves to a text file you will probably be interested in tutorials of [saving form submissions to a database](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-processing.html).

This is by no means a trivial task, but there are certainly many tutorials online for processing forms with php.

Comment: i already got to find the answer.. i got it wrong in the php script.. but i got it now.. thank you though..

Comment: @suffocationkills that's good to hear. So if this is the same solution you're using you can mark this answer as accepted to increase the number of people who respond to your future question.